# open .rar with exe and extract it

Tags: c++

[image]
I want to create a C++ code that extracts the .rar with the

```
system("unrar e c:\myFiles.rar");
```

for example

but how can I get the name and the path of the .rar if I opened it with the exe that have the system code

As the photo i need to open the apk/zip/rar with the exe I made and want the exe to detect the path and the name of the apk/rar/zip needed to be extracted

Comment: Check folder and filenames after extraction?

Comment: no i mean i want to open the rar with the exe i made and let the code detect the file name that was opened by to be extracted

Comment: @DasserBasyouni it is still not clear what you are asking for. Please provide a better example. What are you looking to achieve?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have edited it with a photo to me understand, sorry or the lack of description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your exe in the Windows Registry as being able to handle apk/zip/rar files:

[File Types and File Associations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144104.aspx)

[How to Register a File Type for a New Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127451.aspx)

For example:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    .rar
        (Default) = "RarFile"

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    RarFile
        shell
            OpenWithMyApp
                command
                    (Default) = ""C:\Path to\myapp.exe" "%1""
```

Then, when a user clicks on such a file in Windows Explorer, it can run your exe, and you can use the `argv` parameter of `main()` to detect the filename, eg:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        char cmd[512];
        sprintf(cmd, "unrar e %s", argv[1]);
        system(cmd);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Or

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc > 1)
    {
        std::string cmd = std::string("unrar e ") + argv[1];
        std::system(cmd.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you so, but how after using int argc, char *argv[] in main
i could use in system("unrar e c:\myFiles.rar", argv[1]);
that code gives me error in stdlib.h line number 360 
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW system (const char*);

Comment: std::string give me error is it the library?, i have tried string, string.h, stringstream nothing works

Comment: @DasserBasyouni you marked the question as `c++`. `<string>` is a standard C++ header, and `std::string` is a standard C++ class. Any C++ compiler will be able to compile this code. You are clearly using MingGW, are you using it in C  or C++ mode?

Comment: i am trying just your code with adb commands instad of rar cmd commands and thats is the fully code nothing more
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
system("C:\\adb connect 192.168.101.11:5555");
if (argc > 1)
    {
        char cmd[204800];
        std::string cmd = std::string("adb install") + argv[1];
        system(cmd.c_str());
    }
    return 0;
system("pause");
}
not working

Comment: @DasserBasyouni you have two variables in the same scope both named `cmd`. That is not legal code, you should be getting a compiler error. Get rid of the `char cmd[]` variable, you are not using it anyway. Also, in your `"adb install"` command, you need to add a space character at the end to separate `install` from the filename: `"adb install "`.

Comment: oh thanks you so much that was really unnoticed for me, now its work